# blackbox exporter not coming up as service

Tags: service, systemctl, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Blackbox exporter of prometheus is not coming up as service.

When I run command from `ExecStart` it just works fine.

Would like to know what's missing from below configuration.

```
pwd ; cat blackbox_exporter.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system
[Unit]
Description=Blackbox Exporter Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/opt/blackbox_exporter/blackbox_exporter --config.file=/etc/prometheus/blackbox.yml --web.listen-address="<hostNameGoesHere>:9115"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And all files are with `root` privilege only.

```
ls -l blackbox_exporter.service /opt/blackbox_exporter/blackbox_exporter /etc/prometheus/blackbox.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      343 Oct  4 06:55 blackbox_exporter.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      775 May  3 05:46 /etc/prometheus/blackbox.yml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16074005 Feb 27  2018 /opt/blackbox_exporter/blackbox_exporter
```

Error message is as per below.

```
systemctl status blackbox_exporter.service
● blackbox_exporter.service - Blackbox Exporter Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/blackbox_exporter.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since <TIMESTAMP>; 2s ago
  Process: 101522 ExecStart=/opt/blackbox_exporter/blackbox_exporter --config.file=/etc/prometheus/blackbox.yml --web.listen-address="<hostNameGoesHere>:9115" **(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 101522 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**

 systemd[1]: Unit blackbox_exporter.service entered failed state.
 systemd[1]: blackbox_exporter.service failed.
 systemd[1]: blackbox_exporter.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
 systemd[1]: Stopped Blackbox Exporter Service.
 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for blackbox_exporter.service
 systemd[1]: Failed to start Blackbox Exporter Service.
 systemd[1]: Unit blackbox_exporter.service entered failed state.
 systemd[1]: blackbox_exporter.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed double quotes : "" from `ExecStart` line & it just worked like a charm!!

```
ExecStart=/opt/blackbox_exporter/blackbox_exporter --config.file=/etc/prometheus/blackbox.yml --web.listen-address=<hostNameGoesHere>:9115
```